# Необходимо написать программу на языке Си

Tags: c, функции, параметры

Функция принимает символы. Сформировать строку из переданных символов; если очередной символ - '#', то предыдущий символ в строку не включать (например, для "asd# 89yui##" результатом будет "as 89") - то есть решётки также не включаются в строку. Сама функция должна быть с переменным количеством параметров, первый из которых передаёт количество последующих. Буду запредельно благодарен всем, кто сможет подсказать.

Comment: и в чем у вас именно проблема? ну кроме сессии

Comment: Покажите ваш код и мы его починим.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача простая, просто проверяй текущий символ. Если он оказался "#" то тебе нужно предыдущий символ в строке заменить на пробел, но тебе важно учитывать чтобы текущая позиция строки была не 0, иначе будет ошибка выхода за границы массива и все.